# LED glowing a bit even when Transistor is in off condition

Tags: led, switches, bjt

The LED is connected in between an NPN bjt and 2.4K Resistor at 30V
A few of these tend to emit a small amount of light even when the transistor is off condition.

Vce (of glowing at off condition) is 28.15 
wheras Vce (When LED is off when Transistor is off) is 28.55/28.60V

Nominal current for the LED is around 10mA.

If this is due to the transistor, what is the reason?

[image]

Comment: obviously the transistor is not off

Comment: Can you note the transistor you are using?

Comment: BC107 is the transistor. How can a LED glow with such a low current

Comment: @KarthikShetty An LED will glow with <1mA, although it may not be visible. All it needs is to have the voltage across the LED exceed its forward voltage for the amount of current you present it (usually about 1.9V for red and ~2-3V for green and blue). Your 30V + 2.4K resistor + BJT could easily do that since your transistor isn't off (if it were, VCE would be straight up 30V since IC would be 0 and the voltage across the resistor would then be 0, giving you 30V on VCE).

Comment: Could you give details on the circuit around your transistor as well? Like how the base is connected, etc? Your BJT is likely still on because something isn't working how you expect with the way you are driving your base.

Comment: Added the schematic.

Comment: @KarthikShetty You missed the important spot. Where is this wire connected to D1 and R23 going to?

Comment: Another similar circuit containing the comparator with diode. It is used to check the if there is a difference greater than 2V between 2 signals

Comment: If the D1/R23 thing isn't it, it could be really badly made obsolete transistors.

Comment: @sephro That is my question... But what I dont understand is with just around .4V change The LED glows which is VISIBLE but  not as bright as it would be during normal operation

Comment: Is your opamp rail-to-rail? Is its VSS connected to -15V? Also, measure the TR1 base voltage when the LED is off.

Comment: Yup... The base voltage is 0.08V

Comment: I have seen red LED's glow with 10 uA. In some cases, if the leakage current is bounded and you understand the cause of it, you can simply put a resistor in parallel with the LED. The resistor value should be chosen so that the drop across the resistor is smaller than the minimum forward voltage of the LED. For example, you could choose to make the resistor voltage drop be 0.5V. This would prevent the LED from glowing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since the base voltage is only 80mV, it pretty much has to be the transistor. **If**..if..if the base voltage is steady and not spiking up to a few hundred mV or more every once in a while. If that is happening, an oscilloscope should be able to catch it.

The specification at room temperature is for 15nA leakage maximum, and no more than 10uA at 150°C. I presume you would have mentioned if the transistor was that hot. 15nA is not enough to light an LED visibly. 15uA might be (a very efficient LED in a dimly lit room).

[image]

To be absolutely sure, **remove R23**. If the LED remains on then transistor leakage (or severe PCB leakage) is your problem.

Comment: I have had problems in real designs where 10 uA caused a faint glow in a red LED. Red LED's seem to be the worst in this regard. In my case, I fixed it by adding a 10k resistor in parallel with the LED.

Comment: @mkeith True enough, but if it's *leaking* 10uA it's either defective or almost 150°C. In the former case, I'd suggest throwing it in the garbage bin since it's so contaminated it will  probably fail soon anyway. And a good transistor is 0.5-2 cents.

Comment: agreed. In my case, I knew exactly why the current was flowing, and the amount of current flow was predictable and bounded. But I agree with your answer above 100%. First confirm that the transistor is leaking, then go from there.

Comment: The problem exists even when the Transistor is pulled down to -15V by removing R23 and i've observed that the rise in Vce is exponential and takes around a minute or so. Could this be due  to some parasitic capacitance across collectr and emitter or is the whole batch of transistors is bad?

Comment: Sounds like the transistors are bad (leaky). Try heating it with a heat gun.